# Find all natural number solutions in Prolog program

Tags: math, prolog

For example if I want to get all possible natural number pairs that sum to 10, how would I get prolog to do that?
If my code is something like this:

```
sumsTo10(X,Y):-
   Z is X+Y,
   Z == 10.
```

Then yes, if I ask if 5 and 5 sum to 10 I get a true as an answer, but I'd like something like this:

```
?-sumsTo10(A,B).
[1,9]
[2,8]
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **C**onstraint **L**ogic **P**rogramming library over **F**inite **D**omains (`clpfd`) for that:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

sumsTo10(X,Y):-
    [X,Y] ins 1..10,
    X + Y #= 10,
    label([X,Y]).
```

This then generates:

```
?- sumsTo10(X,Y).
X = 1,
Y = 9 ;
X = 2,
Y = 8 ;
X = 3,
Y = 7 ;
X = 4,
Y = 6 ;
X = Y, Y = 5 ;
X = 6,
Y = 4 ;
X = 7,
Y = 3 ;
X = 8,
Y = 2 ;
X = 9,
Y = 1.
```

The first line specifies that both `X` and `Y` are in the `1..10` domain (that is 10 inclusive, but that does not matter). The second line is a *constraint*: it restricts the fact that `X + Y` should be equal (`#=`) to `10`. This *only* adds the constraint: it will not ground `X` and `Y` to values where this actually holds, but from the moment `X` and `Y` are (partially) grounded, and the constraint is not met, it will fail. If you for instance set `X` to `10`, it will derive that `Y` can only be `0`, but since `Y` is in the interval `1..10`, that is not possible hence the system will fail.

Finally by using `label([X,Y])` we will assign values in the domain to `X` and `Y` such that the constraint holds.

Answer (score 2):

Your Prolog could provide [between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3. Then

```
?- between(1,10,X), between(1,10,Y), X+Y =:= 10.
X = 1,
Y = 9 ;
X = 2,
Y = 8 ;
X = 3,
Y = 7
...
```